# Efficiently create adjacency matrix from network graph (vice versa) Python NetworkX

Tags: python, matrix, graph, network-programming, networkx

I'm trying to get into creating network graphs and generating sparse matrices from them.  From the wikipedia `Laplacian matrix` example, I decided to try and recreate the following network graph using `networkx`

[image]

**How can one EFFICIENTLY convert between an `adjacency matrix` and a `network graph`?**

For example, if I have a network graph, how can I quickly convert it to an adjacency matrix and if I have an adjacency graph how can I efficiently convert it to a network graph.

Below is my code for doing it and I feel like it's pretty inefficient for larger networks.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sp
import pandas as pd

%matplotlib inline

#Adjacent matrix
adj_matrix = np.matrix([[0,1,0,0,1,0],[1,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0,0]])
adj_sparse = sp.sparse.coo_matrix(adj_matrix, dtype=np.int8)
labels = range(1,7)
DF_adj = pd.DataFrame(adj_sparse.toarray(),index=labels,columns=labels)
print DF_adj

#   1  2  3  4  5  6
#1  0  1  0  0  1  0
#2  1  0  1  0  1  0
#3  0  1  0  1  0  0
#4  0  0  1  0  1  1
#5  1  1  0  1  0  0
#6  0  0  0  1  0  0

#Network graph
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(labels)

#Connect nodes
for i in range(DF_adj.shape[0]):
    col_label = DF_adj.columns[i]
    for j in range(DF_adj.shape[1]):
        row_label = DF_adj.index[j]
        node = DF_adj.iloc[i,j]
        if node == 1:
            G.add_edge(col_label,row_label)


#Draw graph
nx.draw(G,with_labels = True)

#DRAWN GRAPH MATCHES THE GRAPH FROM WIKI

#Recreate adjacency matrix
DF_re = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros([len(G.nodes()),len(G.nodes())]),index=G.nodes(),columns=G.nodes())
for col_label,row_label in G.edges():
    DF_re.loc[col_label,row_label] = 1
    DF_re.loc[row_label,col_label] = 1
print G.edges()
#[(1, 2), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 5), (3, 4), (4, 5), (4, 6)]

print DF_re
#   1  2  3  4  5  6
#1  0  1  0  0  1  0
#2  1  0  1  0  1  0
#3  0  1  0  1  0  0
#4  0  0  1  0  1  1
#5  1  1  0  1  0  0
#6  0  0  0  1  0  0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How to convert from graph to adjacency matrix:

```
import scipy as sp
import networkx as nx
G=nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(100,0.04)
adj_matrix = nx.adjacency_matrix(G)
```

Here's the [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.linalg.graphmatrix.adjacency_matrix.html).

And from adjacency matrix to graph:

```
H=nx.Graph(adj_matrix)  #if it's directed, use H=nx.DiGraph(adj_matrix)
```

Here's the [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/convert.html).

Answer (score 1):

I was confronted with the same problem, and found a solution.
We can use the function *from_numpy_matrix*, which is depicted in official website http://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.7/reference/generated/networkx.convert.from_numpy_matrix.html.
Pay attention that the input data usually needs to be modified by numpy.matrix(). 
The example given is that:

```
    import numpy
    A=numpy.matrix([[1,1],[2,1]])
    G=nx.from_numpy_matrix(A)
```

It's really useful.