# Alternative for matshow()

Tags: python, matrix, matplotlib

I have a `101x101` matrix that I want to visualize graphically. So far I used the function `matshow` from `matplotlib.pyplot` as below:

```
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = np.zeros((101,101))
# do stuff to randomly change some values of A
plt.ion()
plt.matshow(A,cmap='PuBuGn')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

The output looks like this:
[image]

You should view this as an interaction matrix between species, and as you can see there are only three species strongly interacting. That is why it looks appropriate to consider a visualization like the following graph I found in a [paper](http://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1004688), but I do not know if and how this can be implemented in Python:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def old_graph(A):
    plt.matshow(A,cmap='PuBuGn')
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.title(r"abs$\left(\left[\mathbf{A}_{ij} \right ] \right )$ ; SIS=%d"%(sis,), va='bottom')
    plt.show()

def new_graph(A, sis_list=np.zeros(0,int), symmetric=True, fig=None, pos=111):
    #create and edit figure:
    if fig is None:
        fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(pos, projection='polar')
    ax.set_rgrids([1],[' '])
    ax.set_rmax(1)
    ax.set_thetagrids([])
    ax.set_title(r"abs$\left(\left[\mathbf{A}_{ij} \right ] \right )$ ; SIS=%d"%(sis,), va='bottom')
    colormap = plt.get_cmap('PuBuGn')

    # make each species an angle value:
    n_species = A.shape[0]
    angles = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, n_species+1)
    # the radius will always be r_max, and each line
    # will always unite two points:
    r = np.ones((2,))
    # prepare list of lines to sort:
    unordered_pairs_and_values = []
    for index_line in xrange(n_species):
        for index_column in xrange(index_line):
            if symmetric:
                value = A[index_line,index_column]
            else: # not symmetric
                value= abs(A[index_line,index_column]- A[index_column,index_line])
            unordered_pairs_and_values.append([[angles[index_line],angles[index_column]], value])
    # sort the lines (otherwise white lines would cover the 'important' ones):
    ordered_pairs_and_values = sorted(unordered_pairs_and_values, key=lambda pair: pair[1])
    # get the maximum value for scaling:
    I_max = ordered_pairs_and_values[-1][1]
    # plot every line in order:
    for pair in ordered_pairs_and_values:
        ax.plot(pair[0], r, color=colormap(pair[1]/I_max), linewidth=2, alpha=0.8)
    # don't know how to add the colorbar:
    #fig.colorbar(orientation='horizontal')
    # mark the angles:
    ax.plot(angles, np.ones(angles.shape), 'ko')
    # mark the important angles (comment if you don't know which ones are these):
    ax.plot(angles[sis_list],  np.ones(sis_list.shape), 'ro')
    fig.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n_species = 51
    sis = 3 # strongly interacting species
    sis_factor = 4.
    A = np.zeros((n_species,n_species))
    # do stuff to randomly change some values of A:
    for index_line in xrange(n_species):
        for index_column in xrange(index_line+1):
            A[index_line,index_column] = np.random.random()
            A[index_column,index_line] = A[index_line,index_column]

    sis_list = np.random.randint(0,n_species,sis)
    for species in sis_list:
        A[species,:] *= sis_factor
        A[:,species] *= sis_factor
        for species2 in sis_list: # correct crossings
            A[species,species2] /= sis_factor
    # stuff to randomly change some values of A done
    old_graph(A=A)
    new_graph(A=A, sis_list=sis_list, symmetric=True)
```

Old graph:
[image: old_graph]

New graph:
[image]
I still don't know:

- how to enter the colorbar, since it requires a plot that was mapped using a colormap.
- how to remove the r-ticks without rescaling the graph (you can try uncomment `#ax.set_rticks([])`)

And the plot looks better with less interacting species:
[image]

Comment: Before I forget, I only considered half the matrix, since I assumed that when one species interacted with the other that interaction would be equivalent in the opposite direction (and so `A[i,j]` should be equal to `A[j,i]`). Otherwise I wouldn't know which value to use to colour the line between the two species.

Comment: This already helps me a lot. The matrix `A` is not symmetrical in the [paper](http://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1004688), but I suppose the autors only considered half of it as well, otherwise there is no way constructing such diagram as you stated correctly.

Comment: I found [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeightedAdjacencyMatrix.html) for wolfram alpha, and [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.adjacency.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) for Matlab, maybe they are what you want. Finally it seems your work has some parallelisms with networks, found [this answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33773187/efficiently-create-adjacency-matrix-from-network-graph-vice-versa-python-netwo).

Comment: I just remembered: the thickness of the line could also be defined by `A[i][j]-A[j][i]`, which would allow the use of the entire matrix and justify the use of the `abs`, as the difference could be negative. I will edit it in the answer.